# Better in AUC and AUC PR, but lower in the optimal threshold

Tags: model-evaluation, auc, threshold, average-precision

Suppose we have two models; model A and model B. 
Model A outperforms both AUC ROC and AUC PR to model B.
However, when we compare the two models with their optimal threshold values, model B outperforms in both the F score and ROC.
In this case, which model should I pick?
(I'm in the medical diagnosis field.)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community. While asking questions, it is recommended to provide complete details in order to get specific answers.

Broadly, you're asking about **model selection** in **classification problem** while comparing two different models based on some model evaluation metrics.

Model selection depends on many **trade-offs**:

1. **Interpretation Vs Prediction accuracy**: Do you need a simple model that is more interpretable OR a less interpretable model with better performance?
2. Selecting appropriate **model evaluation criteria**: depending upon your objective, you can take a call on what is riskier for you False positives or Falses negatives (a trade-off again). Based on the confusion matrix, we compute different ratios (sensitivity/specificity/precision/etc.)
3. I recommend going through my posts [here](https://learnerworld.tumblr.com/search/performance+evaluation) and decide.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand that it depends on the trade-offs with what I want to convey. However, my question was whether we should prefer the fine-tuned sensitivity/specificity, etc. or threshold-free metrics.

Comment: There's no one size fit all metric. Different metrics have their own pros and cons.